# How to statistically compare changes of two percentages

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, proportion

I plan to conduct an experiment with one between-subjects factor with two levels (control vs. treatment). Respondents will be asked to choose among three options (A vs. B vs. C). (FYI, I plan to collect N = 200 per factor).

Below are predicted/made-up results.

[image]

For the choice of option A, there is a 35% percentage-point decrease from control to treatment (45% to 10%). For the choice of option B, there is a 15% percentage-point decrease from control to treatment (45% to 30%).

Question: I would like to test whether 35% and 15% are statistically different. What test should I use?

Note: I am not comparing the choice probability of a specific option between control and treatment group (for this, I think I need to use a multinomial logistic regression). I want to compare the two percentage changes from control to treatment between choice for A and choice for B.

Comment: What about a proportion test (`prop.test`in R)? For $n=200$, the result of a t-test should be the same, but beware to estimate the variances as $p(1-p)n/(n-1)$ to compute the the test statistic and the degrees of freedom.

Comment: @cdalitz Thank you for your suggestion. Can I ask why do you recommend to  estimate the variances as (1−)/(−1)  instead of the usual variance formula: $$p(1-p)(\frac{1}{n_{1}}+\frac{1}{n_{2}})$$

Comment: I have elaborated the comment into an answer. As you are a new contributor, please allow me the hint: if this actually answers your question, please accept the answer. This will remove your post from the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: @cdalitz Thank you so much for your help. I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test whether the distribution among the threee options is signifcantly different between *Control* and *Treatment*, you can use a $\chi^2$-test. Here is an example in R:

```
> data <- data.frame(Control = 200 * c(0.45, 0.45, 0.1),
+                    Treatment = 200 * c(0.1, 0.3, 0.6))
> chisq.test(data, simulate.p.value=TRUE)
X-squared = 121.97, df = NA, p-value = 0.0004998
```

If you only want to test, whether the change of the proportion in only one option is significant, you can use a *proportion test* or a *t-test*. Here are both versions in R for *Choice A* your example:

```
> N <- 200; p <- 0.45; q <- 0.1
> prop.test(x=N*c(p,q), n=c(N,N), correct=F)
X-squared = 61.442, df = 1, p-value = 4.56e-15
95 percent confidence interval:
0.2694863 0.4305137

> # t-test
> sx2 <- p*(1-p)*N/(N-1)
> sy2 <- q*(1-q)*N/(N-1)
> T <- abs(q - p) / sqrt(sx2/N + sy2/N)
> k <- (N-1) * (sx2/N + sy2/N)^2 / ((sx2/N)^2 + (sy2/N)^2)
> cat(sprintf("p-value from t-test: %f\n", 2*(1-pt(T,k))))
p-value from t-test: 0.000000
```

Note that the R function `prop.test` also gives a confidence interval for the difference, which in most cases is of greater interest than a test for statistical significance.